# Asking if a post about a mathematical characterization of gravitational geons can be potentially interesting for the main site MathOverflow

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-topic

I would like to ask about if a question about the following subject can be potentially interesting and on topic on MathOverflow. I would like **to ask on the main site** of MathOverflow **about the equations for an hypothetical object in theoretical physics: gravitational geons.** I've asked 20 days ago a question at undergraduate level on Mathematical Stack Exchange with title *Gravitational geons: an explanation for mathematicians* and identifier [**4509074**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4509074/gravitational-geons-an-explanation-for-mathematicians), at this ocassion I want to ask on MathOverflow a characterization of the equations  for professional mathematiciasn of what is a gravitational geon, if such characterization makes sense. Maybe additionally I ask for (general) references supporting the answer that can to provide the professor.

I add as general reference that Wikipedia has the article with title [*Geon (physics).*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geon_(physics))

> **Question.** I would like to ask on Meta if a question about the equations/mathematical characterization of gravitational geons can be interesting and on topic on MathOverflow. In such case I would like to ask this question in next few days on the main site MathOverflow. **Many thanks.**

If this question on Meta isn't suitable please add a comment that I can to delete it in next few hours.

I've edited (three days ago) a question on Physics Stack Exchange, this [*Mathematical characterization of gravitational geons*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/726281/mathematical-characterization-of-gravitational-geons), post with identifier **726281** the users of the site were kind adding in the comment thread links about papers related to gravitational geons.

Comment: If this question on Meta isn't suitable (if the question that I want to ask on MathOverflow about gravitational geons isn't interesting) please add a comment that I can to delete it in next few hours.

Comment: If I refer well  John Archibald Wheeler studied geons, as refer the linked Wikipedia article. I add that Wikipedia has an article dedicated to this theoretical physicist. He was the professor and colleague of Feynman. This week I'm reading the (Spanish edition of) book *The Quantum Labyrinth: How Richard Feynman and John Wheeler Revolutionized Time and Reality* by  Paul Halpern (Basic Books, 2017). I'm in Chapter 2, and I know that there is scientific dissemination of idea of geons in this book because these are mentioned in several pages from the Index.

Comment: If "the equations of a gravitational geon" have already been written down, then it would be fair to reproduce them and ask about them on MathOverflow. If no such equations have been written down, then asking for a characterization of the physical concept is more a physics question than a math question, and would be off-topic on MathOverflow.

Comment: Asking a question about the mathematical aspects of geon solutions should be on-topic, as long as it falls under the general "research level" umbrella.

Comment: Many thanks @MattF. I'm not a professional mathematician, and I don't know if such equations characterizing a gravitational geon are in the literature (I'm interested in this but it is difficult to find papers about it), I don't know if the equations (whose  solutions are a gravitational geon) can be written/specificied in mathematical terms (for example Navier-Stokes equations, Wikipedia: "... that describe the motion of viscous fluid", and the characterize the certain solutions and their propierties can be difficult but mathematicians have at least these equations for fluids). +1 .

Comment: Many thanks for your attention @DavidRoberts I've added previously a comment in this thread of comments. Many thanks for your remarks, my intention is edit the post on MathOverflow according the advices of professors here, when it is possible about gravitational geons. +1 for your feedback.

Comment: Many thanks to the professor or user who upvoted this post.